# Trying to rename multiple files with seperate file extensions

Tags: powershell, rename

I'm trying to create a Powershell script that renames 2 seperate file extentions in a folder.

The file extensions are .dwg and .upd, however with my current script it only works for a single file extension and when I try to add the 2nd as I've seen others show, it doesnt work.

```
$curDir = Get-Location

Get-ChildItem $curDir *.dwg,*.upd | 
Foreach-Object  { Rename-Item $_.FullName ($_.FullName -replace "-_P\d+","" -replace "_X\d","")
```

Seperate, the .upd and .dwg work, but if I combine the 2 extensions in the script, the script stops working

Example name:
P220529-50-ST.001-007-PRD-_P220529-1000_X1-R00.dwg/upd

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `-Filter` parameter on Get-ChildItem can only be used on a single pattern. If your script is to recurse through subfolders, you could use parameter `-Include` for that, but since you are not recursing, I'd do this:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path $curDir -File) |
Where-Object { $_.Extension -match '\.(dwg|upd)'} |
Rename-Item -NewName {$_.FullName  -replace "-_P\d+|_X\d"} -WhatIf
```

You can remove the `-WhatIf` safety switch after you have confirmed the messages in the console do lead to the wanted replacements. With that switch, nothing gets renamed, it will only show you what *would* happen.

<sup>The brackets around the Get-ChildItem part is to make sure that completes before sending the results through the pipeline. Without that, chances are it will also pick up files that have already been renamed</sup>